# Edge contraction problem in graphs vs in algebraic topology

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-topology

I have a really Naive question.

I was reading [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022000083900120) on graph theory where it classifies the edge contraction problem as an NP-hard problem where it cannot be solved in a linear time.

On the other hand, I've been thinking about turning graphs into simplicial complexes first and then applying the edge contraction on it. While looking for ways to do that, I saw the algorithms and the technique mentioned [here](https://gudhi.inria.fr/doc/latest/group__contr.html) in which the edges of a simplex are being contracted in a linear run time.

I'd say I don't really understand what's going on here. Is it that the simplicial way of edge contraction is a specific case of the graphs or can we really solve this in a linear run time?

Comment: Have you actually _read_ the the definition of the edge contraction problem posed in the abstract of the paper you linked? You are very much comparing apples and oranges here.

Comment: @BenSteffan Yes I did, and I'd appreciate a little less harsh kinda comment :)) That's basically my question, I admitted I'm asking a naive question and just wanna see where I am going wrong! If I could figure it out I wouldn't ask it here!! I know I am doing sth wrong! But still, we know that graphs are basically 1-complexes, so why can't we use the alg top way to solve it?

Comment: Forgive my harshness, but having read the problem you will know that it is about finding a subset of edges whose contraction results in a graph with a special property. It is completely unclear how being able to do a contraction in linear time would help you here, and if you have a specific algorithm in mind that makes use of this then you should have asked about that specifically.

Answer (score 1):

From the abstract of the paper you linked:

> For a property $π$ on graphs, the corresponding edge-contraction problem $P_{EC}(π)$ is defined as follows: Given a graph $G$, find a set of edges of minimum cardinality whose contraction results in a graph satisfying property $π$.

You can contract any edge, in fact any subset of edges in linear time, but that's completely irrelevant to the edge-contraction problem.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. So let's say I want to do edge contraction so that my graph is chordal at the end. So here my property $\pi$ is being chordal and I understand this is a NP-hard problem. Now getting back to the alg top solution, I can make a graph to be a 1-complex, then I can give that to the algorithm I linked and that gives me a reduced version which in fact is chordal as it's a simplicial complex. I don't know where I am going wrong here tbh

Comment: @User-123 The NP-hard part is finding the edges you need to contract, not doing the contraction.

Comment: I see, it makes much more sense now, but I still have some questions. So in the Gudhi algorithm, when they say that the algorithm runs in linear time, aren't they basically saying that the time to find and contract the edges in  a way that the final simplex preserving the geometry is linear? The whole algorithm seems to work in linear time, so this is what makes me confused. Sorry if it's a stupid question

Comment: While I cannot guess what the "Gudhi algorithm" is, what I can suggest is that with any algorithm you very carefully read the statement, with attention paid to the format of the input and how the size of the input is measured. Whatever the Gudhi algorithm might be (assuming it is a true algorithm) then to say that it runs in linear time means that there exists a linear function $L(x)$ having the property that if the input has size $x$ then the time for the algorithm to run is bounded by $L(x)$.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thanks for the explanation. Here's the Gudhi algorithm(https://gudhi.inria.fr/doc/latest/group__contr.html). I am still confused about the whole thing, but I thought we could simply use that algorithm to contract some edges and get a simplified chordal graph at the end. There's also this algorithm that turns a graph into a simplex(https://appliedtopology.github.io/javaplex/doc/edu/stanford/math/plex4/examples/SimplexStreamExamples.html), so I was thinking that we can probably combine the two methods to have a better way of contracting edges to get a chordal graph.

Comment: The Gudhi algorithm you link to does not seem to try to find the *minimum* number of edges that need to be contracted to achieve its goal. In fact, it advertises itself as contracting *lots and lots* of edges while still preserving the homology.